# Enum in WPF ComboxBox with localized names

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, enums, localization

I have a ComboBox listing an Enum.

```
enum StatusEnum {
    Open = 1, Closed = 2, InProgress = 3
}

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding StatusList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStatus}" />
```

I want to display localized names for the enum values in English

```
Open
Closed
In Progress
```

but also in German (and other languages in the future)

```
Offen
Geschlossen
In Arbeit
```

In my ViewModel using

```
public IEnumerable<StatusEnum> StatusList 
{
    get 
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(StatusEnum)).Cast<StatusEnum>();
    }
}
```

only gets me the names of the enum in the code and not the translated ones.

I have general localization in place and can access them using i.e.

```
Resources.Strings.InProgress
```

which gets me the translation for the current language.

How can I bind the localization automatically?

Comment: Do you already have a localization system of some sort in place? If so, details? Or should we just get you to a `string GetValue(StatusEnum status)` method and let you localize from there?

Comment: I have localization in place. I just need to figure it out for enums Binding,

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's an example of the simple `Enum` to translated string converter.

```
public sealed class EnumToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        { return null; }

        return Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(value.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string str = (string)value;

        foreach (object enumValue in Enum.GetValues(targetType))
        {
            if (str == Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(enumValue.ToString()))
            { return enumValue; }
        }

        throw new ArgumentException(null, "value");
    }
}
```

Also you need a `MarkupExtension` which will provide values:

```
public sealed class EnumerateExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }

    public EnumerateExtension(Type type)
    {
        this.Type = type;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        string[] names = Enum.GetNames(Type);
        string[] values = new string[names.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
        { values[i] = Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(names[i]); }

        return values;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{local:Enumerate {x:Type local:StatusEnum}}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStatus, Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter}}" />
```

**EDIT:** You can make a more complex value converter and markup extension. The `EnumToStringConverter` can use `DescriptionAttribute`'s to get the translated strings. And the `EnumerateExtension` can use `TypeConverter.GetStandardValues()` and a converter. This allows to get standard values of the specified type (not only `Enum`s) and convert them to strings or something another depending on the converter.

Example:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{local:Enumerate {x:Type sg:CultureInfo}, Converter={StaticResource CultureToNameConverter}}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCulture, Converter={StaticResource CultureToNameConverter}}" />
```

**EDIT:** The more complex solution described above is published on [GitHub](https://github.com/YohDeadfall/Enumerate) now.

Comment: That's a great solution on the View level

Comment: For anyone else pulling out their hair, you also need `<local:ColorSurfaceEnumToString x:Key="ColorSurfaceEnumToString" />` in `Window.Resources` for `StaticResource` to be resolved.

Comment: This does not seem to work for a Binding to a Property of type `Nullabe<StatusEnum>?`: `System.ArgumentException: Type provided must be an Enum. Arg_ParamName_Name` on the line with foreach in EnumToStringConverter

Answer (score 2):

You can't, out of the box.

But you can create an `ObservableList<KeyValuePair<StatusEnum, string>>` property and fill it with your enum/localized text and then bind it to your `ComboBox`.

As for the string itself:

```
var localizedText = (string)Application.Current.FindResource("YourEnumStringName");
```

Getting the Enum string representation with `Enum.GetName`/`Enum.GetNames` methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can do using a Attribute for the enum and writing an extension method for the enum. Refer the below code.

```
<ComboBox Width="200" Height="25" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboSource}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Value"
          SelectedValuePath="Key"/>


public class MainViewModel
{
    public List<KeyValuePair<Status, string>> ComboSource { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ComboSource = new List<KeyValuePair<Status, string>>();
        Status st=Status.Open;
        ComboSource = re.GetValuesForComboBox<Status>();
    }
}

public enum Status
{
    [Description("Open")]
    Open,
    [Description("Closed")]
    Closed,
    [Description("InProgress")]
    InProgress
}

 public static class ExtensionMethods
    {
        public static List<KeyValuePair<T, string>> GetValuesForComboBox<T>(this Enum theEnum)
        {
            List<KeyValuePair<T, string>> _comboBoxItemSource = null;
            if (_comboBoxItemSource == null)
            {
                _comboBoxItemSource = new List<KeyValuePair<T, string>>();
                foreach (T level in Enum.GetValues(typeof(T)))
                {
                    string Description = string.Empty;
                    FieldInfo fieldInfo = level.GetType().GetField(level.ToString());
                    DescriptionAttribute[] attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
                    if (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
                    {
                        Description = GetDataFromResourceFile(attributes.FirstOrDefault().Description);
                    }
                    KeyValuePair<T, string> TypeKeyValue = new KeyValuePair<T, string>(level, Description);
                    _comboBoxItemSource.Add(TypeKeyValue);
                }
            }
            return _comboBoxItemSource;
        }

        public static string GetDataFromResourceFile(string key)
        {
            //Do you logic to get from resource file based on key for a language.
        }
    }
```

I have already posted a similar thing in SO [Is it possible to databind to a Enum, and show user-friendly values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27572843/is-it-possible-to-databind-to-a-enum-and-show-user-friendly-values/27573155#27573155)